# How can i remove redundant brackets from my output JSONFILE?

Tags: java, json, dependencies

I am using a maeven dependecie that maintain the order of key values of java, but the prblem is that display a double bracket when i m usin a jsonArray. Can someone tell me where my mistake is.

`mssgErreurResult()` is a method that return an Arraylist that contains all my error messages. Just imagine that `Errors ...` in the JsonFile is the return of that method

What i get :

```
{
  "complet": false,
  "erreurs": [
    [
   "Errors ..."
    ]
  ]
}
```

What i want:

```
{
  "complet": false,
  "erreurs":[
   "Errors ..."
    ]
}
```

The method i used:

```
public void ecrireFichierJSon(String fichierSortie) throws
            FichierJsonInvalideException, org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException {

        org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject completOrNot = new org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject();
        completOrNot.put("complet", mssgErreurResult().size() <= 0);
        org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray messagesErreur = new org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray();
        messagesErreur.put(mssgErreurResult());
        completOrNot.put("erreurs", messagesErreur);

        try {
            Files.write(Paths.get(fichierSortie), completOrNot.toString().getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new FichierJsonInvalideException(e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `mssgErreurResult()`?

Comment: @LHCHIN `mssgErreurResult()` is a method that return an Arraylist that contains all my error messages. Just imagine that `Errors ...` in the JsonFile is the return of that method

Answer (score 1):

It is added with extra [ ... ] by org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray messagesErreur, try to remove it and use the following instead

```
completOrNot.put("erreurs", mssgErreurResult());
```